# How do I combine multiple filter query and should of Elastic Search using Java Library (QueryBuilder)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a query like below :

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "age": {
                        "from": 57,
                        "to": null,
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "terms": {
                    "_id": [
                        "1212yas1",
                        "sdfsfs1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "should": [
            {
                "query_string": {
                 "query": "(football) OR (Cricket)",
                "default_field": "hobbies.hobby"
      }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I am very new to Elastic Search, I want to implement above query using Java library of Elastic Search how can I do this?

hobbies is nested object, age is long.

Comment: What is version of Elasticsearch. are you using Java highlevel client or new Java client ?

Answer (score 1):

First things is that, You need to use `IDs` type of query as you are search on `_id` field.

If you are using **Java high level client** then you can use below code:

```java
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(new RangeQueryBuilder("age").from(57))
                .filter(new IdsQueryBuilder().addIds("1212yas1", "sdfsfs1"))
                .should(new QueryStringQueryBuilder("(football) OR (Cricket)").defaultField("hobbies.hobby"));

SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(query);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

If you are using **new Java client** then you can use below code:

```java
Query query = Query.of(
                q -> q.bool(BoolQuery.of(bq -> bq.filter(f -> f.range(RangeQuery.of(rq -> rq.field("age").from("57"))))
                        .filter(f -> f.ids(IdsQuery.of(iq -> iq.values("1212yas1", "sdfsfs1"))))
                        .should(s -> s.queryString(QueryStringQuery
                                .of(qs -> qs.query("(football) OR (Cricket)").defaultField("hobbies.hobby")))))));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new Java Client Api, try the code bellow:

```
var query = Query.of(q -> q.bool(BoolQuery.of(bq -> bq
    .filter(f -> f
        .range(RangeQuery.of(rq -> rq.field("age").from("57"))))
    .filter(f -> f
        .ids(IdsQuery.of(ids -> ids.values(List.of("1212yas1", "sdfsfs1")))))
    .should(s -> s.queryString(
        QueryStringQuery.of(qs -> qs.query("(football) OR (Cricket)").defaultField("hobbies.hobby"))))
)));

var response = client.search(SearchRequest.of(sr -> sr
    .index("idx_name")
    .size(10)
    .query(query)
), Entity.class);
```

Comment: it will be better to use `ids` query insted of `terms` query for `_id` field.